# Multiprocessing can only join a started process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following Python code

```
jobs = []
p = Process(target=self.verify_process, args=(vm_ha1, creds, run_cmd_ha1, ip_ha1))
jobs.append(p)
p.start()
p = Process(target=self.verify_process, args=(vm_ha2, creds, run_cmd_ha2, ip_ha2))
jobs.append(p)
p.start
p = Process(target=self.verify_process, args=(vm_client, creds, run_cmd_client, ip_client))
jobs.append(p)
p.start
for p in jobs:
    p.join()
```

The target is a small def checking if a process on a VM has finished, and will print the exit code.

When this is running, I get an error after the first process is finished, and writing its output

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 144, in join
    assert self._popen is not None, 'can only join a started process'
AssertionError: can only join a started process
```

When I was looking around for this, I found a few mentions of this.
And most of them were because they were all using `p.run()` and should use `p.start()`.

But I'm using `p.start()` already.

This is the first time I'm tying out Multiprocessing, so it is possible I'm using it incorrectly.

From what I can see all 3 processes should be started.

Comment: `p.start` -> `p.start()`, you need to actually call start method.

Comment: I feel so dumb. Just after posting it here I saw the error with the missing parenthesis on the 2nd and 3rd process run, dooohhhhh :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis for the second and third `p.start`. It should be:

```
p.start()
```